# Appengine deployment file count

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

What contributes to the number of files that are created?
I assume the number of gwt permutations is a multiplier, but what factors sum up to the constant variable? static files, source files, etc? What, if anything, should I keep in mind to keep the file count low(er)?

```
Scanning files on local disk.
Scanned 250 files.
Scanned 500 files.
Scanned 750 files.
Scanned 1000 files.
Scanned 1250 files.
Scanned 1500 files.
Initiating update.
Cloning 926 static files.
Cloned 100 files.
Cloned 200 files.
Cloned 300 files.
Cloned 400 files.
Cloned 500 files.
Cloned 600 files.
Cloned 700 files.
Cloned 800 files.
Cloned 900 files.
Cloning 734 application files.
Cloned 100 files.
Cloned 200 files.
Cloned 300 files.
Cloned 400 files.
Cloned 500 files.
Cloned 600 files.
Cloned 700 files.
Uploading 997 files.
Uploaded 249 files.
Uploaded 498 files.
Uploaded 747 files.
Uploaded 996 files.
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of files. Can you tell us more about your project? Is it a GWT app for example?

Comment: @Jason It is a gwt/appengine app, yes.

Comment: What kind of deferred binding rules are you using, to generate this many permutations?  40 languages * 5 browsers would only net ~200 permutations, and even that's pretty extreme.

Comment: I have a total of 12 permutations. 6 for browsers times 2 for geolocation functionality.

Comment: @antony any versioning system with hidden files?

Comment: @system yes indeed, svn. they're being included!?

Comment: @antony it could be, .svn for example.

Comment: @system how do I exclude them then? and exclude from what: the gwt compiler, or the app engine deployment?

Comment: I can't find anything talking about version control housekeeping folders being an issue for app engine and/or gwt.

Comment: @antony check [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/392fb7c6226d7a67/c1648a388e07428a?lnk=gst&q=svn+skipping#c1648a388e07428a)

Comment: I'll have to play around with that. <exclude path="**/.svn" /> doesn't seem to do what I think it should do.

Comment: I am pretty aggressive with my gwt code splits, which contributes to the size of war/<modules>/deferredjs/**. maybe I'm too aggressive. I also have two gwt modules that are dependant on each other, which duplicates both of those modules' compiled js code.

Comment: I just thought to go count how many source files there are, and there are just over 800 source files, so the numbers above don't seem as far off what they should be anymore.

Comment: the .svn folders and files are only contributing a few handfuls of files, if any at all. There's just a lot of source code and code splitting going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that ends up in the war folder, including compiled gwt modules, compiled java code, static files, jars, etc.

Scanned 2500 files.
Cloning 962 static files.
Cloning 1693 application files.

/war -> 1793 files

/war/ -> 478*2+30 -> 986 files
/war/WEB-INF -> 744 files

/war/WEB-INF/classes -> 655 files